# RegEx to replace simple abbreviations

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace each abbreviation like this: `e.g.`. That means one character, one dot, one character and one dot. Leading and trailing space.
But this is not working:

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\s([A-z]\.[A-z]\.)\s', 'g'), 'abbreviation<$1>')
```

*Example*

```
Lorem e.g. ipsum
```

Should get

```
Lorem abbreviation<e.g.> ipsum
```

Comment: `[A-z]` doesn't match what you think: the ASCII range from uppercase letters to lowercase includes some non-letter characters too. Try `[A-Za-z]`, or the ignore case option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[A-z]` doesn't match what you think: the ASCII range from uppercase letters to lowercase includes some non-letter characters too. Try `[A-Za-z]`, or the ignore case option:

```js
console.log("Lorem e.g. ipsum".replace(/\s([a-z]\.[a-z]\.)\s/gi, ' abbreviation<$1> '))
```

Answer (score 0):

in `new Regexp` syntax the string argument should have escaped slashes.

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\\s([A-Za-z]\\.[A-Za-z]\\.)\\s', 'g'), ' abbreviation<$1>')
```

Comment: @mplungjan [A-z] is equivalent to  [A-Za-z] as they form a continuos ASCII charecter range. Thats why it worked for me when i tested. notice that the z is small letter

Comment: See [*Why is this regex allowing a caret?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)

Comment: @Sagi_Avinash_Varma: please check ASCII codes 91-96! Even if it happens to match this particular case, you should never use `[A-Za-z]` to match letters only.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do a bunch, so I'd define an array of objects like this.

```
var str = 'The FBI and NASA work for the US government'
var abbr = [
    { 
        short: 'FBI',
        long: 'Federal Bureau of Investigation'
    },
    { 
        short: 'NASA',
        long: 'National Aeronautics and Space Administration'
    },
    {
        short: 'US',
        long: 'United States'
    }
];
```

Then loop over them and replace like this:

```
for (var a = 0; a < abbr.length; a++) {
    str = str.replace(abbr[a].short, abbr[a].short + ' (' + abbr[a].long + ')');
}
```

Then you can `console.log(str)` and you get

```
FBI (Federal Bureau of Investigation) and NASA (National Aeronautics and Space Administration) work for the US (United States) government
```